# Setting a fixed whitespace for text

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS, so I apologise if this question is a bit simple.

I have a nav-bar that sits in the centre of my page and has a width of 'x'

What I want to do is create white space for my `<p>` text, so that if you drew two vertical lines; that touch the ends of the nav bar, the text always touches the the vertical lines - regardless of window size.

My current solution makes the text move relative to the window size, whereas I want my text to align with the nav bar on the vertical axis whilst being justified.

Here's a picture of what I want to make it clearer:

[image: png]

Here's my current solution that only works if the window size is right:

HTML:

```html
<p id="body"> blah blah ..... </p>
```

CSS:

```css
#body {
   margin: 25px 310px 25px 310px;
   text-align: justify;
   line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. If you give the nav bar the same horizontal margins as the p, they will line up. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/QLT8a/) I made, showing the lack of problem. Unless you aren't explaining it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the same width to the 'p' and center margin it, just as the nav bar.

**HTML**

```
<div id='navbar'></div
<p id="body"> blah blah ..... </p>
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar, p {
   width: 900px;
   margin: 10px auto;
}

p {
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Noe both your 'navbar' and 'p' align vertically as you need them.